# Grid View / List View with Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, jquery-masonry

i'm sitting on this problem since 2 days.
http://jsfiddle.net/DSk8D/

i want to implement jquery.masonry with the grid view, but the jquery hook is wrong `$('#products.grid').masonry({` ?
only on refresh it works a bit - eh strange. 
i tried so many things but nothing worked.

I will be very thankful for help.

Comment: The selector works for me. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: sure. i want to switch trough the list view and the grid view with the 2-Buttons "grid" and "list" at the top of the demo how you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/DSk8D/ - The jquery masonry plugin only works if i push the "Grid-Button" and then refresh the page or only refresh. (delete please the cookies to see what I mean)

Answer (score 0):

When you want the grid view on document ready you need to assign the grid class to the products id after the document is loaded:

```
 $("#products").addClass("grid");
```

. 
If possible you can add it to your html template:

```
 <div id="products" class="grid">
```